# C# Button Click Event with an if statement won't display toast notifcation

Tags: c#

Why will this click event not display the first toast message?

I created a break point and it hits the line to display "Waiting on User Input..." but never displays. I only get a 5 second wait and then an Approved or Declined toast notification.

```
    private void Button_Credit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        myToast.Show("Waiting on User Input...");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (pc.BuildTransaction())
            myToast.Show("Approved");
        else
            myToast.Show("Declined");

    }
```

Comment: You are blocking your UI-Thread with `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);`. The Dispatcher has no chance to draw your notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Thread.Sleep`, but instead utilize `Task.Delay`, so you're not blocking the current thread during your specified delay.

If you block your current thread, which in this situation is much likely your UI thread, how do you expect it to be able to dispatch your toast notification?

Comment: This makes sense.  If i were actually utilizing BuildTransaction() the delay would be built in.  I was attempting to simulate the delay and that was the root of all of my issues.  Thanks for the quick response!